# Regex for number after a Parenthesis (

Tags: python, regex

I have a column with values like this:

```
4 (3 in force)
44 (39 in force)
```

I was able to use this to get a new column for the first number.

```
df['new'] = df['column'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

How can I get a new column for the second number? (3,39, etc.)

Comment: Will the format between the two `()` ever change?

Answer (score 0):

One way that specifically answers you question would be to use a lookbehind regular expression, that basically says "the first number after another number, a space and a parenthesis":

```
df['new'] = df['column'].str.extract('(?<=\d+\s\()\d+')
```

But if you're extracting multiple parts from a single string, you might consider combining the two and using groups in the regex to access the parts you want.

Answer (score -1):

You could just take the row, convert it into a string, split it, and access the needed numbers, for example:

```
row = '4 (3 in force)'
row.split(' ') # This returns ['4', '(3', 'in', 'force)']
row.split(' ')[1] # This returns '(3'
row.split(' ')[1][1:] # And this returns all numbers after the bracket, so '3'
```

Comment: This gets the desired result, but doesn't use a regex, which is what the OP was asking about (given the tag of the question)